# Consul constantly removes service

Tags: consul

I had added a consul agent to the host in client mode and added a service.
And now, it constantly and silently removes the service and registers again

```
2017/01/27 08:25:23 [INFO] consul: member 'static' joined, marking health alive
2017/01/27 08:26:23 [INFO] consul: member 'static' joined, marking health alive
2017/01/27 08:28:23 [INFO] consul: member 'static' joined, marking health alive
2017/01/27 08:29:23 [INFO] consul: member 'static' joined, marking health alive
2017/01/27 08:30:23 [INFO] consul: member 'static' joined, marking health alive
2017/01/27 08:31:23 [INFO] consul: member 'static' joined, marking health alive
2017/01/27 08:33:23 [INFO] consul: member 'static' joined, marking health alive
2017/01/27 08:35:23 [INFO] consul: member 'static' joined, marking health alive
2017/01/27 08:37:23 [INFO] consul: member 'static' joined, marking health alive
```

The service config is simple

```
{
  "service": {
    "tags": [
      "master"
    ],
    "address": "172.16.50.40",
    "port": 5432,
    "name": "staging-postgres"
  }
}
```

Is it posible to register a service forever and deregister only manually?

Comment: Have you tried to register directly to a consul server instead of client?

Answer (score 1):

Consul services are usually registered to a specific node (member). When that member leaves the cluster, it is assumed that all its services are also unhealthy, therefore they are marked as unhealthy.

It would be helpful to know why "static" continues to join and leave the cluster. If that's a behavior that cannot be prevented, it might be best to register your service as an [external service](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/external.html).

```
$ curl -X PUT -d '{"Datacenter": "dc1", "Node": "google",
   "Address": "www.google.com",
   "Service": {"Service": "search", "Port": 80}}'
   http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/catalog/register
```